# To find an execution line-counter for Java IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, counter

**Is there any plugin to some IDE that show the number of times a line is run in the code?**

Eclipse's ECLemma does not seem to have a setting to show execution times at the left-hand-side bar, like in the service WebCat.

Comment: Hmm, this might actually be better suited for SO.

Comment: @mmyers - plugins for an IDE can be answered on SU, but in this case, it's very specific, so it could have more answers on SO indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [eclipse test and performance tools plateform](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) would be able to help you with this. It includes a profiler which will instrument your code and provide the information you want. 
Careful with profiling, it can be a heavy performance hit depending on how many functions/classes you monitor

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the breakpoint properties in eclipse may be you can configure a variable to capture the hitcount

Answer (score 1):

The focus of code coverage is only if a line is executed or not. Nothing more.

To get counters you would have to look at profiler software and not code coverage.

There are plugins for both Eclipse and Netbeans. I am not sure if they show counters per line, but I think that they show counters per method, which might be what you want...

[image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://jmvanel.free.fr/images/parser4j_profile_netbeans.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with writing to a log file or to screen or using a counter?

Answer (score -1):

In NetBeans 6.8 there is a nice code coverage tool which does pretty much that what you want but actually only for ruby. (right click project -> code coverage)

But could you use an ant task or maven plugin? Then Take a look at [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage)